# Error in Database (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, database

```
incorrect string value: \xF0\x9F\x92\x95
```

how to solve it? this happens when I enter product data

Comment: Try posting db related questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CHARACTER SET` of the *column* needs to be utf8mb4.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for confirmation.

Also, the connection needs to be utf8mb4 (or `UTF-8`, depending on the client language).  Let's see the connection parameters.

Give a try with below solution.

I was finally able to figure out the issue.
I had to change some settings in mysql configuration my.ini 
This article helped a lot
http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4#character-sets

First i changed the character set in my.ini to utf8mb4
Next i ran the following commands in mysql client

```
SET NAMES utf8mb4; 
ALTER DATABASE dreams_twitter CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

Use the following command to check that the changes are made

```
SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';
```

Comment: Will the data stored on the database remain or will be lost?

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14516003/which-is-the-better-way-to-change-the-character-set-for-huge-data-tables